# How to convert date and time from one time zone to another in when GMT format is given in android

Tags: android, timezone

I have a particular date and time of +10:00 GMT (Australia/Melbourne)which is coming from google api in the following format :-

**2015-05-12T14:00:00.000+10:00**

Now, I want to convert the above time according to device current time zone.

For example :-

The above time in +5:30 GMT (India) should be **2015-05-12 9:30:00**

How can I achieve it ?

My below code is :-

```
    SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date parsed = null;
    try {
        parsed = sourceFormat.parse("2015-05-12 14:00:00");
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } // => Date is in UTC now

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    destFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

    String result = destFormat.format(parsed);

    System.out.println(result);
```

But the result is 2015-05-12 19:30 which is wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

referring to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timezone_gettimezone.htm) i think you are wrong with the `getTimeZone("GMT")`

you should use `getTimeZone("GMT+10:00"));` because GMT is the +/-0:00

have a look at the doc i posted :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,its working here

```
 try {


SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+10"));

//Local time zone
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

//Time in GMT
String date = dateFormatLocal.format(dateFormatGmt.parse("2015-05-12 14:00:00"));
LogUtil.LOGD(Constants.ACTIVITY_TAG, "Date- " + date);
}catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [Joda library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to make life easier.

```
private String showTimeStringExample(String timeStamp) {
    //timestamp = "2015-05-12T14:00:00.000+10:00"

    // use Joda to parse the time stamp and convert it to java
    final Date date = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseDateTime(timeStamp).toDate();

    // use the format you had in your question, setting the locale to the device's default
    SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            getResources().getConfiguration().locale
    );

    // comes out as "2015-05-12 05:00:00 in the UK
    return destFormat.format(date);
}
```

Gradle dependency:

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
```